# C++ windows.h How to use variable in ShellExecute

Tags: c++, winapi, clion

I want to ask how to use variable inside the `ShellExecute`

In my case I want to add a path to a file.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::string path={"C:\Users\Me\CLionProjects\storage\cmake-build-debug\bookshop.txt"};

ShellExecute(NULL,"edit","path",NULL,NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

return 0;
}
```

I've tryed with `c_str()` but it does not help. It is compiling without an error but txt file not oppening.  Any clues ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash characters: `std::string path={"C:\\Users\\Me\\CLionProjects\\storage\\cmake-build-debug\\bookshop.txt"};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes in your string literal, and get rid of the braces:

```
std::string path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\CLionProjects\\storage\\cmake-build-debug\\bookshop.txt";
```

You then need to use the `std::string::c_str()` method to pass your string to `ShellExecute()`.   And since you are using `std::string`, you should use the `char`-based `ShellExecuteA()` instead of the `TCHAR`-based `ShellExecute()`:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "edit", path.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```